# Spool output multiple tables involved in query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I am trying to find efficient ways to pull a large amount of data from a database, to put it on a cloud platform for analysis (for technical reasons there's no way of doing this in an automated way). For the big tables, I'd like to extract CSVs of a month's worth of data at a time; however, one huge table doesn't have dates, and the IDs have a prefix so I can't simply get a range of IDs. So I think I'd have to join onto another table. Something like this:

```sql
select * from big_table
inner join (
select * from table2 where date between to_date("'2020-04-01'","yyyy-mm-dd") and to_date("'2020-05-01'","yyyy-mm-dd") query_result
on big_table.id = query_result.id
```

Thing is, I want to be able to spool to CSV the results of both this query and the inner query into separate files. The inner query can take some time to run (approx 8 minutes), so ideally I'd want to run the whole query above and export to two locations, rather than run the above query and the inner query as separate tasks (thereby duplicating the work).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can spool to two locations at the same time.  But you could create a temporary table and use that:

```
create temp table temp_table2 as
    select t2.*
    from table2 t2
    where date >= date '2020-04-01' and
          date < date '2020-05-01';
```

Then, you might want to create an index on this:

```
create index idx_temp_table2_id on table2(id);
```

Then:

```
select bt.*
from big_table bt join
     temp_table2 t2
     on bt.id = t2.id;
```

You would still need to spool them spearately.

Note:  A simple index on `table2(date)` might be sufficient to speed *both* queries.